# Android PathMeasure getMatrix() - Help finding flags

Tags: android, path

Can someone please help me find a list of flags that are needed by PathMeasure.getMatrix()

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PathMeasure.html#getMatrix(float, android.graphics.Matrix, int)][1]

[1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PathMeasure.html#getMatrix(float, android.graphics.Matrix, int)

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a quick guess, I would say one/both of the constants at the top of that page: `POSITION_MATRIX_FLAG` or `TANGENT_MATRIX_FLAG`.

Hopefully, that helps you in the right direction as I haven't done any work with graphics myself.